# Django, combining a list of QuerySets into 1 Queryset

Tags: python, html, django, postgresql

So I am building a clothing comparer in Django. I have created multiple checkboxes so that people can filter the products into for instance: Jackets and Trousers. To get all the products in my Postgresql database I made a dictionary with the keys being the categories and the values being the words that are linked to the category. If a match is found the products get appended to a list which contains all the products I want to show. The problem is that I have multiple QuerySets in that list and I cant output it to my HTML. Is there a way to combine all the QuerySets in the list into one QuerySet? The code:

```
mylist = request.POST.getlist('checkbox')
    categorie_list = ['jackets', 'sweaters', 't-shirts', 'polo-shirts', 'trousers', 'shorts', 'hats', 'bags']
    cat_dict = {'jackets': ['zip-up', 'jacket', 'overshirt', 'parka'], 'sweaters': ['hoodie', 'sweatshirt', 'jumper']}
    list1 = []
    for item in mylist:
        if item in categorie_list:
            if item in cat_dict.keys():
                print(item)
                for value in cat_dict[item]:
                    print(value)
                    data = models.Product.objects.filter(name__regex=value)
                    list1.append(data)
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass

    print(list1)
```

list1 looks something like this:

```
[<QuerySet [<Product: >, <Product: >]>, <QuerySet [<Product: >, <Product: >]>, <QuerySet [<Product: >, <Product: >]>]
```

model looks like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    brand = models.TextField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    color = models.TextField(null=True)
    final_price = models.TextField()
    initial_price = models.TextField()
    sort_price = models.TextField()
    product_link = models.TextField()
    image_link = models.TextField()
    discount = models.TextField()
    company_pic = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this. Here we filter values as list datatype.

```
data = list(models.Product.objects.filter(name__regex=value))
list1.append(data)
```

please add your model for more information.

Comment: Ah thanks this works, but now I have problems with outputting it in HTML. The data usually looks something like this: <QuerySet [<Product>, <Product> etc]>. And now it looks like this: [[<Product>, <Product>]]